# Rails row count with order displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

H,

I am trying to display the count (in order ie 1st, 2nd, 3rd...) of rows in a table.

```
Order.create(user_id: 1, created_on: '2016-09-29') - should display 1st
Order.create(user_id: 1, created_on: '2016-09-30') - should display 2nd
Order.create(user_id: 2, created_on: '2016-09-29') - should display 1st
Order.create(user_id: 3, created_on: '2016-09-28') - should display 1st
Order.create(user_id: 1, created_on: '2016-10-29') - should display 3rd
```

How can I achieve this in rails?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to display on the page the amount of orders a particular user had made ie if it is their first order - I would like to display (1st) or if it is their second - 2nd...). But I am unsure how I can achieve this in rails. I am very new to rails.

Comment: Check http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/ and search for `counter_cache` in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference